# Как получить текстовое значения сразу из нескольких div с одинаковым классом?

Tags: javascript

```
   <div class="panel"> 
     <div class="hit">0</div> 
     <div class="hit _active">1</div>  
     <div class="hit _active">3</div> 
     <div class="hit _active">5</div> 
     </div>
```

На странице есть 4 div с однаковым класом. В этих классах есть цифры от 0 до 9.
Мне нужно сделать уловие if, что-бы  при всех нулях в дивах остановить Setinterval.
Понимаю что нужно применить querySelectorAll и у и меня даже получается закрашивать все эти дивы.

```
const Elts = document.querySelectorAll('.hit');
  Elts.forEach(function (Elt) {
  Elt.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

Но как сделать код , что-бы остановить Setinterval незнаю.

```
if(......innerText === '0'){clearInterval(myint);}
```

Comment: у элементов с 0 убирается класс `_active`? Этот класс на странице используется где-то еще?

Comment: Grundy, Да убирается, но не у всех. У последнего хоть и ноль будет, но класс _active так и останется.  _active больше не используется.

Answer (score 0):

[every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const elts = document.querySelectorAll('.hit')
//elts.forEach((e) => e.style.backgroundColor = 'red')

const hasZero = () => [...elts].every((e) => e.textContent == '0')
console.log(hasZero())

elts.forEach((e) => e.textContent = '0')

if (hasZero()) {
  console.log(true)
  // clearInterval(myint)
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="hit">0</div>
  <div class="hit _active">1</div>
  <div class="hit _active">3</div>
  <div class="hit _active">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Например так

```
let i = 0;
const elts = document.querySelectorAll('.hit');
elts.forEach(e => { i += parseInt(e.textContent); });
if (i == 0) { clearInterval(myint); }
```

Comment: TemirStack, да это то-что надо. Осталось ещё решить вопрос, что-бы этот код срабатывал не только при обновлении страницы. Как-бы сделать так, что-бы когда появлялись нули срабатывал этот код.

Comment: Вставить этот код в функцию и вызывать её где нужно. Например, в конце функции, которая обновляет div'ы.